# Need help to do data recovery on my external hard disk

Tags: data-recovery

I was unable to access my WD NAS drive after almost 3yrs of usage. With all the googling, I reckon the ultimate solution is to remove the casing and these are what I have done so far:

1. Attach the drive to my laptop using a SATA cable.
2. Downloaded Ubuntu on my SanDisk usb thumbdrive and boot up from USB
3. Tried to access my files on my hard disk drive but don't know how to (read that it was supposedly quite simple but...).

Unfortunately, I'm stuck and not sure how to proceed. I have taken a screenshot after trying a long time to even locate my hard disk drive (pls pardon me! Feel like an idiot...) but couldn't upload that picture (error: Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur).

But in short, I managed to locate my hard disk (Device: /dev/sdc1) and it shows 4 partitions. Under Assessment, it says SMART is not supported. Does it refer to a different file format or that my hard disk is corrupted (I really hope it isn't!)? Can some kind soul help me out and guide me please? Thank you so much in advance!

PS: I'd  love to upload the screen shot if possible. So if someone can guide me, it'll be great!

Comment: Can't you see the hard disk in File Manager? (/media)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the following informations: 1) primary OS on Laptop 2) Ubuntu release 12.04 or 13.04 3) Output of this terminal command `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 0):

When you have your computer running off the usb drive you should be able to see your disk in the file manager. From there you should be able to copy paste the files to say a usb harddrive.

When a disk supports SMART you can see how many hours it has been used in its life, how many powercycles it has had, the current temperature and how many bad sectors there are (if any) and more. If your disk doesn't support it, thats ok. If it supports it but its not working because the disk is failing.. that wouldn't be good.

You could manually mount the partition:
Do `sudo fdisk -l` to list partitions.
Identify which partition is the one you need to access.
You will need a folder to mount it to.
Lets make one: `sudo mkdir /media/mountfolder` Then mount your partition to the folder you just made: `sudo mount /dev/sdXX /media/mountfolder`
where /dev/sdXX is the partition you wish to mount.
If all went well you should be able to access it. If you're not sure how to get to /media/mountfolder you can get nautilus to open it for you with: `nautilus /media/mountfolder`